# Is there any way to use SBT's resolver only for subset of artifacts?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there any way to define custom resolver that would be used only for subset of artifacts, more specifically to fetch artifacts only with predefined `groupId`?

For example, project defines a custom `FooResolver` that should be used only for artifacts with `groupId` `org.foo` but all other artifacts should be resolved using the default resolver.

Answer (score 1):

To add unmanaged dependencies to an SBT project, the simplest solution is to just put the jars in the `lib` folder in your project. All libraries in the `lib` folder will be in the classpath by default.

If you want to use another folder instead of `lib`, you can redefine it:

```
unmanagedBase := // provide a java.io.File here.
```

If you want to do something more complex: SBT retrieves unmanaged libraries with the `unmanagedJars` task, so you can always redefine that task (but that would probably be a sign that you're trying to do something too complicated to reasonably use unmanaged dependencies...).

Comment: I want to add a managed dependency, just use a specific resolver to fetch them and only them (e. g., project defines a custom `FooResolver` that should be used only for artifacts with `groupId` `org.foo` but all other artifacts should be resolved using the default resolver).

_Added example to a question_

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question. I'm not sure what is the best way to do this; but managed dependencies are retrieved by the `update` task, so you will probably have to refine that task.